# Merge several branch commits to master

Tags: git, github, merge

Is it possible to merge several, but not all git commits in a branch to the master branch?

For example, say I add several commits (1,2 and 3) in the branch 'test'. They are all related to file test.py, but there are no conflict.
How can i merge commits 1 and 2, but not commit 3

Preferably I would like a GUI tool.

Comment: `git merge` merges one [see footnote] *commit*. So for this particular case, just `git merge` the second commit, rather than the third. However, the form of your question indicates that you misunderstand what `git merge` does, so you should read up on it. (Maybe this is why you got downvoted? I didn't do the downvote, I have no idea who did.) [footnote] Git has what it calls "octopus merges" that merge more than one commit, but this means something quite different from what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If the commits are in order like in your question, as torek mentioned in a comment, you should just use `git merge <2>` (where `<2>` is any way of referencing what you call commit 2 in your question: for instance the SHA-1 hash or `test^` for the second-to-last commit in the branch `test`.

More generally, you can use `git cherry-pick` to pick out the changes made by specific commits in `test`, like so:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <1>
git cherry-pick <2>
... #However many more you want to cherry pick
```

Note that this is not actually a merge: it replays your commits on top of the master branch. This is how it has to be, though: it doesn't make sense to merge part of a branch. If you want it to be a merge instead, you can make a new branch at the commit where `test` diverged from `master`, cherry pick the commits you want, and then merge that branch.